# How to run rake cucumber:wip with zeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, zeus

For my Rails app, I use zeus to speed up development.

For my first feature/scenario, I used `zeus cucumber` which worked perfectly, but now I have 2 features and I wanted to be able to test only the second feature.

Before using zeus, I used to test with `rake cucumber:ok` or `rake cucumber:wip`

So now, I want to run `rake cucumber:wip` with zeus

I tried `zeus cucumber:wip` but it's not working:

> Could not find command "cucumber:wip"

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zeus cucumber --profile wip` is the only way to launch cucumber with the real fastness of zeus.

Comment: This is the only way of doing it !! YOU ROCK !! :D